# Сохранение данных в FIrebase согласно алгоритму

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

Пишу на Flutter. Есть задача сохранить клиента в момент регистрации. Но смысл в том чтобы id был кастомным(перед созданием данного клиента, сперва запрос идет на сервер и id будет возвращаться с этого сервера). И потом я хотел бы клиента сохранить с этим id в Firebase database.

Есть определенный объект oAuthUser который возвращается после его сохранения на удаленном сервере. Но при запросе возвращается Permission denied. Вот исходники:

```
userManagement.createUser(user.user.uid.toString(), {
            'id': user.user.uid.toString(),
            'user_name': _nameController.text.toString(),
            'email': _emailController.text,
          }).CatchError((e) {
            print(e.toString());
          });

class UserManagement {
  Firestore firestore = Firestore.instance;
  FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.instance;

  createUser(String uid, Map data) {
    database
        .reference()
        .child("oauth_users/$uid")
        .push()
        .set(data);
  }
}
```

Собственно сама ошибка из логов: setValue at /oauth_users/123213/-LvAwA_1I43ZIVj6IN_m failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied

Вопрос один. Как организовать логику чтобы клиент успешно сохранился в firebase database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот, попробуйте так (для Firebase Database):

```
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';

final databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();

void main(){
// ...

createData(user.user.uid.toString(), _nameController.text.toString(), _emailController.text.toString());

getData();

updateData(user.user.uid.toString(), _nameController.text.toString(), _emailController.text.toString());

deleteData(user.user.uid.toString());

// ...
}

void createData(string id, string userName, string email){
    databaseReference.child(id).set({
        'user_name': userName,
        'email': email',
    });
}

void getData(){
  databaseReference.once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    print('Data : ${snapshot.value}');
    // TODO: return snapshot.value;
  });
}

void updateData(string id, string userName, string email){
  databaseReference.child('1').update({
    'user_name': 'userName',
    'email': email',
  });
}

void deleteData(string id){
  databaseReference.child(id).remove();
}
```

Comment: вот ошибка setValue at /clients/123213/-LvAwA_1I43ZIVj6IN_m failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied

Comment: В правилах Firebase Database дайте разрешения на чтение и изменения:
`{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}`. И попробуйте заново.

Comment: а можно ли задать для write(так как мне нужно именно сохранение) задать true но только при наличии айдишника?

Comment: Да, [ознакомитесь с документацией](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security)